# Authentification and authorization in asp.net 5 mongodb and angular2

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm developing a web API using asp.net 5 dnx framework and a client in angular2.
I want to implement authentication and authorization for my web service.  I heard about Microsoft identity, but I'm using mongodb. 
I read this article:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298973/rest-api-security-stored-token-vs-jwt-vs-oauth

It describe the 3 best ways for securing a web service. I find that JWT is perfect in my case. 
My question is, how can I implement that in my case (asp.net 5, mongoDb, angular2)?

Comment: its too early to answer this question - .aspnet core (or aspnet5) is changing too frequently. dnx will soon be retired

Comment: dnx will soon be retired ?plz  where did you find that ??

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B812